# GGPlot2 Boxplot only shows lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm working on data `elo_blatter` from the the `fivethirtyeight` package and I want to make a boxplot of `population` by `confederation`

This is my code:

```
sp <- elo_blatter %>% group_by(conf = confederation) %>% summarise(population = sum(popu06, na.rm = TRUE))
```

and for the boxplot:

```
mp %>% 
    group_by(conf) %>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=conf, y=population, fill=conf)) + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + 
    labs(x = "",y = "") + 
    theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")
```

and it looks like this

[image: this]

how fix it

if i use normal date it looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W6iO.png)

Comment: You plot the summarized dataframe which contains only one value per confederation. Hence your boxplot shows only "lines". Simply use the original non-summarized data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you code

```
... %>% summarise(population = sum(popu06, na.rm = TRUE))
```

R will return the population **sum** for each confederation, which is a **single value**. Hence, when you draw a boxplot, it will only show lines, because the value for each confederation is only its sum. Unless if each confederation holds a **vector of values**, then we can know the median, range, etc.

I'm not really sure what are you trying to show. In my opinion, instead of using a boxplot, I think it will be better if you use **barplot** to compare the population among different confederations.